# C# Merge CSV files with different Headers

Tags: c#, csv, merge

Im trying to merge two csv files which have different headers. When I do it the second file adds to the bottom of the csv file rather to the "right" of it.
eg. 
file 1 has headers of (with data in each column)
Col A, Col B, Col C 
file 2 has header of (with data in each column)
Col F, col F, Col F

After the merge in file 1 I want it to read

col A, b, c, d, e, f

data of columns

(with the coresponding data in each column) but my merge is adding it to the bottom of the file so it read like

a, b, c

data of file 1

d, e, f

data of file 2

When i do what I thought would in c#

```
string file1 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file1.csv");
        string file2 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file2.csv");
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\file2.csv", string.Concat(file1, file2));
```

or

```
File.AppendAllText(@"C:\file1.csv", file2);
```

or using a stream reader

```
StreamWriter wtr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\file1.csv");
wtr.Write(file1 + "\t" + file2); //tried different variations with this one
wtr.Close();
wtr.Dispose();
```

all give me the same result with no joy.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you want `Enumerable.Zip`.

Comment: i'm trying really hard to imagine how you could validate that each line (from the 2nd file) is a match across the width of this structure... boggling :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to join them line by line, not one after the other.  There's no built-in way to do this in the framework, so you have to code it yourself.

Your main problem is going to be handling situations where the files don't have the same number of lines.  If they are guaranteed always to have this, then the operation is relatively simple.  Here's some C#-like pseudocode which illustrates the naive solution:

```
var first = File.ReadAllLines("firstfile.csv");
var second = File.ReadAllLines("secondfile.csv");
var result = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => string.Join(",", f, s));
File.WriteAllLines("combined.csv", result);
```

`File.ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings, one per line.  You can easily read in and break a file into individual lines this way.

`.Zip` is a Linq extension method (you must include it by adding a `using` statement for `System.Linq` at the top of your file) that joins two enumerables together, one item at a time, like a zipper.  It passes each line into a func you supply which performs the join--in this case, `(f, s) => string.Join(",", f, s)`.

`string.join` is a convenient method for concatenating strings that are separated by static text.  In this case, the text is a comma ",".  It's more useful in other situations, but I use it here because I can.

And `File.WriteAllLines` writes the contents of an enumerable of strings to a file.

Now, if you have to handle the situation where the enumerables are different lengths, you'll have to step through each line of each collection and join them manually into an output collection, adding in empty columns for the missing data.  That's a bit more complex, but can de done.  Try it yourself if you have to handle this situation, then come back if you have problems and ask a new question with details from your code.

Comment: that is great, thank you very much, works like a charm. Thankfully the files will always have the same number of lines so this will work for me.

Comment: @CM99 Note that `File.ReadAllLines` is going to read the entire file into memory if you ever need to do this on significantly large files it could result in out of memory exceptions.  In that case you'd want to use `File.ReadLines` instead.

Comment: thank Juharr, ill keep that in mind. really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
string separator = ","; //Change this to whatever column separator you want.
var file1 = File.ReadLines(@"C:\file1.csv");
var file2 = File.ReadLines(@"C:\file2.csv");
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\file2.csv", file1.Zip(file2, (f1, f2) => f1 + separator + f2);
```

First using [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) will result in an `IEnumerable<string>` that will read each line of the file when you iterate it.  The [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method then allows you to join up two enumerables based on relative position within each enumerable.  Finally [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx) will iterate the result of `Zip` and write each line to your file.

Also note that if the files do not have the same number of lines the result of `Zip` will stop when it reaches the end of one of the files.

Comment: please edit to `string[] file1` and `string[] file2`. And note that if `file1` has more lines than `file2` (or the other way) `Zip` ignores those lines!

Comment: @RenéVogt Added the note about file length difference, but the result of `ReadLines` is a`IEnumerable<string>`, not `string[]`, but I just changed it to `var`.

Comment: ok, my bad, though it was `string[]` (but definitly not `string` ;) )